# numpy invalid dot product shape

Tags: python, numpy

As part of my exercise with Numpy, i tried below code.

```
import numpy as np

inputAttributes  = 32
outputAttributes = 64
noOfElements = 3


inputData = np.random.random((noOfElements, inputAttributes))
weights = np.random.random((outputAttributes, inputAttributes))

extrawegiths = np.random.random((outputAttributes, outputAttributes))
extraInput = np.random.random((outputAttributes,))

eachLayerOutput =[]

for eachData in inputData:
    print ("---------------")
    print (weights.shape, eachData.shape)
    print (extrawegiths.shape, extraInput.shape)
    result = np.dot(weights,eachData)  +  np.dot(extrawegiths, extraInput)          
    print (result.shape)
    print ("---------------")
```

My output was as below:

```
((64, 32), (32,))
((64, 64), (64,))
(64,)
```

If I interpret, then

```
  (64, 32 ) * (32, ) => (64, )

  (64, 64 ) * (64, ) => (64, )

  (64,    ) + (64, ) => (64, )
```

So far good, Now i change extraInput Shape to **#appending '1'**

```
extraInput = np.random.random((outputAttributes, 1)
```

Now, i got the result which i m unable to understand.

```
((64, 32), (32,))
((64, 64), (64, 1))
(64, 64)
```

If I interpret, then

```
  (64, 32 ) * (32, ) => (64, )

  (64, 64 ) * (64,1) => (64,1)

  (64,    ) + (64, 1) => (64, 64 )
```

**HOW (64,) + (64, 1)  LEADS TO (64,64) ?**

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the **trailing dimensions**, and works its way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> ```
>    1. they are equal, or
>    2. one of them is 1
> ```

The last dimension of one of your arrays is 1, invoking rule 2.

If you want to keep the array shape as `(64,)` or as `(64, 1)` I would suggest being explicit:

Assuming `a` has shape (64,) and `b` has shape (64,1):

```
a + b[:,0]          # shape (64,)
a[:,np.newaxis] + b # shape (64, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. the exact confusion is stll on  np.random.random((32,)) gives me 1 row and 32 columns, where  as np.random.random(32,1) give me, 32 rows of each 1 column. is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Whoami Correct, but I think it would be easier to think in terms of the shape of the array. It is not a 1-1 correspondence to rows and columns in a matrix. (32,) is not the same as (1,32), but they will behave very similarily in this case.

Comment: (32,) is not same as (1,32).  Valid. That's why i see iterating (64,32) matrix row-wise, i get the output shape(32,)  but actually i was expecting (1,32). Any specific reason behind this?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I'm not sure if I understand your problem If it is related, you could add it to the question post. numpy's dot product will sum over the last axis of first matrix with second to last axis of second matrix, while normal broadcasting rules will always favour the last axis if it is of same size or 1.